# Android game framework concept

Tags: android, android-framework

I'm building a game based on a framework that was illustrated in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430239875). From what I can tell, the framework is similar to other such frameworks that are geared towards making games, rather than other types of apps. It's proving quite helpful in most cases, but I don't fully understand how I would go about launching a "traditional" Activity. Specifically, I want to open up an Activity that contains a ScrollView, but am a bit lost on how this fits into the whole game framework paradigm... especially when it seems that gaming frameworks do rendering by updating a Canvas, rather than by dealing with individual Activity elements.

For example, the "framework way" of launching a new screen look like:

```
game.setScreen(new HelpScreen(game));
```

where HelpScreen is a Java class that extends a Screen class. I'd like to know the best practices way for opening a "traditional" Activity (i.e. one that is laid out via an XML file). (Or am I just going about this the wrong way?)

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

In Android you use an Intent to launch a desired Activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity